# zsh parse error: condition expected

Tags: shell, zsh

```
getListing () {
    if [ "$1" = ""];
    then
        alcListDir ~/Projects/Haskell/ -f \
            | alcSortPath time | tac | xargs -n1 basename
    else
        alcListDir ~/Projects/Haskell/"$1"/ -f \
            | alcSortPath time | tac | xargs -n1 basename | sed -e "s/^/"$1"\//"
    fi
}
```

The above is giving me an error (when run with `set -x`) of:

```
+./rofi.sh:29> getListing ''
+getListing:1> [ '' '=' ']'
getListing:1: parse error: condition expected:
```

I'm invoking the function like so: `getListing ""`

What is the cause of the error?

Comment: Typo: No space between `""` and `]`.  That statement is also better written as `if [ -z "$1" ]`.  And the `sed` call leaves `$1` unquoted. Don't break out of the double quotes for `$1` there.

Comment: The funny thing here is the error message, "condition expected". What I suppose happens is that since `""]` results in the final `]` that `[` wants, it thinks you tried to use a two-argument expression (not counting the `]`). The first arg should then be a condition and the second the operand to that condition. All conditions start with a dash, so anything else gives "condition expected". It's just hard to read here since there first arg is the empty string. `[ foo = ]` would give `zsh:1: parse error: condition expected: foo` which at least shows _where_ it expected the condition to be.